# Are there any electric fields associated to the scalar fields in quantum field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

We know that electric field due to stationary charges is given by gradient of phi.
In quantum field theory the scalar fields associated with bosons doesn't have any electric fields but while dealing with em fields we get vector E as conjugate momenta to A_u. why there are not any electric fields associated to such scalar fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand your question, perhaps you can clarify. Also, the boson mediating the electromagnetic interaction is a spin-1 particle, not a scalar which would be spin-0.

First of all, a electric field and  a field in quantum field theory are not the same thing. The former is a measurable quantity for instance, while the second is a [second-quantized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_quantization) field of a classical field theory. In classical electrodynamics the electric field is given by

$$\vec{E} = - \nabla \phi - \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \vec{A}$$

If we put $\phi$ and $\vec{A}$ together in the 4-vector $A_\mu$ we find the electric fields in the [field strength tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor) $F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$.

From the $F_{\mu\nu}$ we can construct a classical field theory which if second-quantized correctly (which does lead to some problems) gives quantum electrodynamics QED where we identify the gauge bosons with photons, the quanta of electric fields. Note that we only talk of bosons once we quantize and find a spin-1 particle in the spectrum.

So it is by construction that the electric field is in this way associated to the Lorentz vector $A_\mu$. There are certainly fields associated to other particles such as the scalar Higgs field.

Comment: what is the difference between phi in the first equation(above)  and the phi which is a field associated to bosons.

Comment: aren't  bosons mediating em interaction are photons having spin o. please clarify on this point.

Comment: The photon has spin 1 as a simple search would show.
The two $\phi$ are different things. The first is just the classical potential we know from electrostatics. The notion of (gauge) particles, i.e. photons is something that appears once we second-quantize the theory. Then $\phi(x)$ denotes a field operator.  I would suggest reading some introductory textbooks to second quantization e.g. the one by Schwabl, or the above Wikipedia article.